# gradle location is incorrect

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am setting gradle home in fedora 24,but the intellij idea show that

```
gradle location is incorrect
```

Like this:

[image]

This is how to get my gradle home:

```
[root@bogon dolphin]# gradle getHomeDir
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
:getHomeDir
/root/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/3.1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.638 secs
```

Comment: What does `which gradle` show?

Comment: Is IntelliJ running as root? Would IntelliJ have access to the gradle home dir?

Comment: @Ashutosh Jindal What should i do if intellij is not running as root,because  install gradle must have root privillege in Fedora

Comment: Could try starting IntelliJ from terminal as the root user? See Tools -> create command line launcher

Comment: @Bajal  [root@bogon ~]# which gradle
/root/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin/gradle

Comment: @Bajal /root/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin/gradle